# Magento 2: extension installation module outdated issue

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install a magento 2 extension. Facing this exception error on website.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade 
your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
******_*** schema: current version - 1.0.1, required version - 1.0.0
******_*** data: current version - 1.0.1, required version - 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As error displays its solution. You have to fire the following command using Magento cli,

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
>   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

if you still found the same error message you should remove entry from `setup_module` table and re run the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there is a module (the one you marked with `***_***`) that is at a higher version than it is required.
Not sure how this happened.
But you can do one of the following.

- edit `module.xml` of the module in question and set the version to `1.0.1`
- run this query `update setup_module set data_version = '1.0.0', schema_version = '1.0..' where module = 'your module name here';`

I would go with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to the DataBase and remove the rows from the modules which give the error. Then run:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*; php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope it helps.